# pandas writing to excel sheet deleting other sheets in file

Tags: excel, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have simple code to export python dataframe to existing excel file with sheets
but the writer keep deleting the existing sheet from the file

```
read = pd.ExcelFile('Saw_Load.xlsx')
print(read.sheet_names)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Saw_Load.xlsx')
result.to_excel(writer,'saw', index = False)
read2 = pd.ExcelFile('Saw_Load.xlsx')
print(read2.sheet_names)
writer.save()
```

Here is the output i am getting

```
['saw', 'Pivot']
['saw']
```

We can clearly see before to_excel function was used there were 2 sheets (saw,Pivot).  After there  is only one 'saw'

It could be a simple fix in formula but couldn't seem to find anything that works.  Any help will be appreciated

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to write to an existing excel file without overwriting data (using pandas)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20219254/how-to-write-to-an-existing-excel-file-without-overwriting-data-using-pandas)

Comment: @BruceWayne Thanks I tried the solution in that sheet and it worked although it seems to corrupt the file and remove some special formatting from other tabs.  eg it worked with pivot table but corrupted the file when slicer was added.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your problem is that **you're not writing again the old `sheets`** that the book contains. Let's say that you need to write it from scratch again, but no to execute `to_excel` again but just specify the workbook.

This happens beacause `xlsxwriter` creates a new file, so the old one is **erased**.

You can do it by using `writer.book` and `writer.sheets` objects.

```
excelBook = load_workbook(filename)
with pd.ExcelWriter(filename, engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
    # Save your file workbook as base
    writer.book = excelBook
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in excelBook.worksheets)

    # Now here add your new sheets
    result.to_excel(writer,'saw', index = False)

    # Save the file
    writer.save()
```

Note: please notice that I've used `load_workbook` from `openpyxl`, but you can use `Excelfile` without it and reproduce it with just minor changes.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue as the OP. I adopted your code, but got the following error: *AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'*. I'm writing into a test xlsx worbook that has three tabs including the one I'm writing into. No other formatting added. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're having a problem with the selected engine. Check this other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59794843/xlsxwriter-error-attributeerror-workbook-object-has-no-attribute-add-format

Comment: that is correct. I switched to openpyxl and it worked following the solution here which is similar to yous: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049148/python-update-dataframe-to-existing-excel-sheet-without-overwriting-contents-on. thanks

Comment: "Property 'book' cannot be set" :(

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('Saw_load.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a") as writer:
    result.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="name_of_sheet")
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't had success getting this to intelligently add data. With write mode 'a', i get an extra sheet e.g. Sheet1 even if it already exists. With write mode 'w', it deletes any previous information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the if_sheet_exists parameter with values of either `replace` or `overlay`.

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine="openpyxl", mode="a" if_sheet_exists="overlay") as writer:
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="name_of_sheet")
```

Comment: I believe it is "if_sheet_exists", not "if_sheets_exists"

Answer (score -2):

Try this (although I'm not sure where `result` came from):

```
read = pd.ExcelFile('Saw_Load.xlsx')
print(read.sheet_names)
_writer = pd.ExcelWriter('Saw_Load.xlsx')
result.to_excel(_writer,'saw', index = False)
```

Idea [from here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html):

> If passing an existing ExcelWriter object, then the sheet will be added to the existing workbook.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to add the writer command,  I had the writer command in my original file. Still got the same output