# xlsxwriter error: AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'

Tags: python, conditional-formatting, xlsxwriter

I'm doing some simple conditional formatting using xlsxwriter but I am getting this error when I run the code below.

```
AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'add_format'
```

I have updated xlsxwriter and looked at a lot of questions on SO and documentation but nothing has worked yet.

This is my code:

```
workbook = load_workbook(input_excel_filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(input_excel_filename, engine="xlsxwriter")
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)

trends_sheet = writer.sheets["Trends"]
slight_increase = writer.book.add_format({"bg_color":"#d3e6d5"})
trends_sheet.conditional_format("E:E", {"type":"cell", "criteria":"==", "value":"Slight Increase", "format":slight_increase})
```

Comment: What's the type of `writer.book`?

Answer (score 14):

Check if xlsxwriter package is installed or not....even I faced the same issue..resolved it after installing the package...same answer goes for any attribute error issue related to workbook/writer if your code is correct

Comment: This solved my problem! Thanks for the big help

Comment: This is a good answer. What I found is upgrading the package worked. `pip install xlsxwriter --upgrade`

Answer (score 5):

## Cause and solution

1. Makesure **variable** is usable

   - such as mine

     - first: `workbook  = writer.book`
     - then: `header_format = workbook.add_format(`
2. Makesure already set `pandas`'s **engine** (here using `xlsxwriter`)

   - when init ExcelWriter, set your engine

     - `writer = pd.ExcelWriter(outputFile, engine='xlsxwriter’, options={'strings_to_urls': False} )`
3. Makesure already installed related lib (`xlsxwriter`)

   - `pip install xlsxwriter`

     - or mine: `pipenv install xlsxwriter`

### Full code for refer

```py
import pandas as pd

writer = pd.ExcelWriter(
    output_final_total_file,
    engine='xlsxwriter',
    options={'strings_to_urls': False}
)

...
df = pd.read_csv(outputExcelFile, sep=pandas_sep)
...
df.to_excel(outputExcelFile.replace('.csv', '.xlsx'), index=False)
...
df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name=SheetNamePay, startrow=1, header=False, index=False)
...

workbook  = writer.book

header_format = workbook.add_format( # !!! here workable, no error
    {
        'bold': True,
        'text_wrap': True,
        # 'valign': 'top',
        'valign': 'center',
        # 'fg_color': '#D7E4BC',
        'bg_color': '#edbd93',
        'border': 1
    }
)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76331344/how-to-merge-empty-cells-in-a-pivot-table-using-python . Please could someone help me with this

Answer (score 1):

Part of the problem was I needed to set `writer.book` explicitly. So add the line `writer.book = workbook` after defining `writer`. Also adding `engine="openpyxl"` to the ExcelWriter got rid of a subsequent error. Altogether this seems to work:

```
workbook = load_workbook(input_excel_filename)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(input_excel_filename, engine="openpyxl")
writer.book = workbook
writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in wb.worksheets)
data.to_excel(writer, sheet_name="Data", index=False)
writer.save()
writer.close()
```

I couldn't get it to work with conditional formatting but setting formatting in the Excel spreadsheet directly actually seems to work, because even if the data is rewritten the formatting stays intact.

Comment: You did not get it work because you set engine to "openpyxl". having xlsxwriter package installed, either set the engine to "xlsxwriter " or just dont set that engine parameter. The default engine is "xlsxwriter " already.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I solved it with specifying the type of the `engine`:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('file.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter') as writer:
```