# Python : How to write on existing xlsx without overwrite other columns

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I just want to overwrite certain column base on my dataframe. Suppose df2 is my dataframe.

Below is the code i use. The problem is its overwrite the other columns and row even though i code it to start on columns 80.

I want its overwrite on column 80 and beyond only, but not before the column 80. 80 is index, not name.

```
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter

df2 = pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\RUI LEONHART\Google Drive\Shop\STOCK V2.xlsx',
    usecols=['XS1','S1','M1','L1','XL1','XXL1'])

# Create a Pandas Excel writer using XlsxWriter as the engine.
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('pandas_simple.xlsx', engine='xlsxwriter')

# Convert the dataframe to an XlsxWriter Excel object.
df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Sheet1', startcol=80)

# Get the xlsxwriter objects from the dataframe writer object.
workbook  = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet1']

# Close the Pandas Excel writer and output the Excel file.
writer.save()
```

I search around the solution. The closest one is this

[python: update dataframe to existing excel sheet without overwriting contents on the same sheet and other sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049148/python-update-dataframe-to-existing-excel-sheet-without-overwriting-contents-on)

but still overwrite the columns and row that i dont want.